# Passing listView data through intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview

I am trying to send selected item to another activity through new intent. But when I click on item, then `application has been stopped working` message displayed and application terminate.
Here is my first activity code

```
public class AndroidListViewActivity extends ListActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // storing string resources into Array
        String[] adobe_products = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.adobe_products);

        // Binding resources Array to ListAdapter

        this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(AndroidListViewActivity.this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.label, adobe_products));

        ListView lv =getListView();
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
                    long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String product = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();


                Intent curentScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleItem.class);
                curentScreen.putExtra("product", product);

                startActivity(curentScreen);
            }
        });         

    }  

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.android_list_view, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Second activity code.

```
public class SingleItem extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.single_list_item_view);
        TextView txtProduct = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.product_label);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        // getting attached intent data
        String product = i.getStringExtra("product");
        // displaying selected product name
        txtProduct.setText(product);

    }
}
```

stacktrace :

```
08-13 14:05:35.678: D/AndroidRuntime(267): Shutting down VM
08-13 14:05:35.698: W/dalvikvm(267): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800) 
08-13 14:05:35.728: E/AndroidRuntime(267): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
08-13 14:05:35.728: E/AndroidRuntime(267): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String 
08-13 14:05:35.728: E/AndroidRuntime(267): at com.list.androidlistviewactivity.AndroidListViewActivity$1.onItemClick(AndroidLi‌​stViewActivity.java:39)     
08-13 14:05:35.728: E/AndroidRuntime(267): at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
08-13 14:05:35.728: E/AndroidRuntime(267): at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3382)
08-13 14:05:35.728: E/AndroidRuntime(267): at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1696) 
08-13 14:05:35.728: E/AndroidRuntime(267): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587) 
08-13 14:05:35.728: E/AndroidRuntime(267): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
08-13 14:05:35.728: E/AndroidRuntime(267): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 
08-13 14:05:35.728: E/AndroidRuntime(267): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627) 
08-13 14:05:35.728: E/AndroidRuntime(267): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-13 14:05:35.728: E/AndroidRuntime(267): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)      
08-13 14:05:35.728: E/AndroidRuntime(267): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868) 
08-13 14:05:35.728: E/AndroidRuntime(267): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626) 
08-13 14:05:35.728: E/AndroidRuntime(267): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post your LogCat Error Message

Comment: LogCat might just be the key, please paste it.

Comment: check your log cat and post the exception here plz.

Comment: post your logcat msg..

Comment: should it not be `TextView tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textview1);
         String product = tv.getText().toString()`?

Comment: i have similar code that u r using it is working fine for the only difference between u r and mine code is i am using getBaseContext() while calling a new intent other things are same

Comment: @AndroidKiller here is my logcat

08-13 14:05:35.678: D/AndroidRuntime(267): Shutting down VM
08-13 14:05:35.698: W/dalvikvm(267): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
08-13 14:05:35.728: E/AndroidRuntime(267): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-13 14:05:35.728: E/AndroidRuntime(267): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String
08-13 14:05:35.728: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at com.list.androidlistviewactivity.AndroidListViewActivity$1.onItemClick(AndroidListViewActivity.java:39)

Comment: 08-13 14:05:35.728: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
08-13 14:05:35.728: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3382)
08-13 14:05:35.728: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1696)
08-13 14:05:35.728: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-13 14:05:35.728: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)

Comment: 08-13 14:05:35.728: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-13 14:05:35.728: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-13 14:05:35.728: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-13 14:05:35.728: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)

Comment: 08-13 14:05:35.728: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-13 14:05:35.728: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-13 14:05:35.728: E/AndroidRuntime(267):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: @LASIAF does my answer work? 10 questions accepted two does the other answers not help you?

Answer (score 3):

Replace this

```
   String product = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
```

with

```
TextView tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.label);  //initialize text view withid label
String product = tv.getText().toString(); //get the text
```

Or

```
String product = (String)parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), product,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Then

```
            Intent curentScreen = new Intent(ActivityName.this, SingleItem.class);
            curentScreen.putExtra("product", product);
            startActivity(curentScreen);
```

Example: here when you click the list row you get to see the toast.

list_item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label" // textview with id label
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources> 
    <string-array name="planets_array">
        <item>Mercury</item>
        <item>Venus</item>
        <item>Earth</item>
        <item>Mars</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String[] planets = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
        this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.label, planets));
        ListView lv =getListView();
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
                    long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                TextView tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.label); 
                String product = tv.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), product,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });         

    }  
}
```

Snap shot

[image]

Comment: perfect one ...i was about to post this any ways

Answer (score 1):

The way you start your second Activity is not right.

Replace your line where you create your Intent

```
Intent curentScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleItem.class);
```

with

```
Intent intent = new Intent(AndroidListViewActivity.this, SingleItem.class);
```

As first argument in the Intent constructor you have to pass the source Activity, i.e. `this`. Since you call the function in the OnItemClickListener, you call it with `AndroidListViewActivity.this`. Hope this solves the error.

Comment: Intent intent = new intent(AndroidListViewActivity.this,SingleItem.class);

Intent intent = new intent(getApplicationContext(),SingleItem.class);

@Terry I Think both work same....??
But my app is working with first one. Thanx..

Answer (score 0):

Instead, you can get a String `product` as below:

Replace the below line in `onItemClick`

```
String product = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
```

with

```
TextView tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textview1); 
String product = tv.getText().toString();
```

Comment: I'd be really interested to see an `ArrayAdapter<String>` would return a `Cursor` object... Change the last two code lines to `String product = (String) lv.getItemAtPosition(pos);` in stead.

Comment: @LASIAF what is line 39

Comment: @AvadhaniY I am not sending textview, i am send selected text from listview.

Comment: With the code above, u will get the selected text from listview only... Have u checked? else, check and let me know if still there is an issue

Comment: @LASIAF see this as u want http://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-listview-tutorial/